# MapKit follow with heading without top down view

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I'm trying to develop an app with a built in navigation feature using Apple Maps. The goal is for it to show the user's current location and rotate to face the direction they are heading in. However, I'd also like it to not view from the top down, more of a tilt, like in Waze.

I can have it follow the user and rotate with the correct heading, etc. using  `.followWithHeading`. But I can't figure out how to have it tilt. I've also tried using a map camera which enables me to tilt it. However, I then can't get the coordinates since I can't use both `didUpdateLocation` and `didUpdateHeading` in a single location manager. Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you get both location and heading updates? What's preventing you?

Comment: @rmaddy I can't for the life of me figure out how. Am i somehow able to have 2 location manager functions?

Comment: Just implement both sets of delegate methods and start both updates.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry if this sounds stupid but could you point me in the right direction as to how I would do that?